# Cryptocurrency contract will not deploy

Tags: contract-deployment

I have recently tried to build my own cryptocurrency on the Ethereum platform and deployed. All seemed to work fine but now the contract is still not deployed / completed. Is it normal that it takes a while sometimes? You can check it here https://etherscan.io/address/0xD0d798A8ecc21C49c9ab29F513C2257083072e97

All the best and thanks for your reply.
Tim

Answer (score 1):

The contract **is** deployed. It is deployed at [0xe1893f9d0b4216e23c0e3fa2b0111079a401a1f0](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe1893f9d0b4216e23c0e3fa2b0111079a401a1f0).

The link posted is (I assume) your Ethereum address. You have submitted a transaction to create a contract, and it has been created.

When you submit a transaction it is not instantly mined. The time it takes to be mined depends on the gas price that you set. Once mined the contract is created.

Comment: Thanks. I did a similar test a couple of minutes ago and then I almost instantly see the contract in my Ethereum wallet under Custom Contracts and Custom Tokens tabs. The contract from earlier is still not visible. Hope I don't aks to stupid questions. Really want to learn how this works!